# The Browser disconnected while convert large File(more 2GB) to base64 string conversion

Tags: javascript

The Browser is disconnected while convert large File(more 2GB) to base64 string conversion.

Comment: disconnected? you mean it fails?

Comment: Where the conversion is made ? Server side ? Client side ? 2go can take 40 mn to 1h to be downloaded, so the session expires.

Comment: The browser is hanged while convert base 64 string more than 1GB files